# Parsing local HTML file using Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have an HTML file containing my contacts. I want to extract each contact with his phone number(s). The problem is there are contacts with no phone numbers and there are others with more than one.

Each contact has a box like this: [image: Contact Box]

And these are the details of the box: [image: Box Details]

I have tried to get all the names as a list and all the phone numbers as a list but it won't make sense if I attached them together. My question is how to attach each phone number to the right contact?
I can ignore the ones don't have any phone number or make it null. Any help?

Comment: How are you reading the html ?

Comment: `with open(r'C:/Users/Khalid/Desktop/Contacts.html','r', encoding="utf-8") as f:

    tree = html.fromstring(f.read())`

Comment: can you provide example of the html? with dummy numbers for privacy

Comment: There are other forms as I explained in my post but this is the main and most common form: https://imgur.com/55MTjAP

Comment: we can't copy and paste html code from an image

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you need. I've downloaded the HTML file and I don't know much about it. All I did is that I searched for parsing and applied it on my file. The class of phone number is `class="_3hls"` and it can exist multiple times or none for one contact. The contact class is `class="_3-96 _2pio _2lek _2lel"`.

Comment: Can you share what you’ve tried? What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Please convert your html to hmtl table then you are able to parse it faster

below is the sample code

```
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd

data = """
<table>
<tr>
<td>name</td>
<td>sample name</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>number</td>
<td>123456789</td>
</tr>
</table>
"""

df = pd.read_html(data, flavor="lxml")[0]

new_header = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = new_header

pprint(df.to_dict('records'))
```